# Is there a way to run MQ on cloud?

Tags: php, cloud, ibm-mq, amqp

I am a PHP developer and have mostly worked in PHP on the web based systems. I know PHP supports AMQP protocols and on a standalone server I can install a broker like Rabbit MQ / Apache MQ etc and use PHP along with it. I have worked earlier with MQ (IBM MQ, Apache MQ, Fusesoft MQ) and I understand that the broker for above have to run on a standalone server (within a LAN/WAN or may be a VPS). I wanted to understand if there is an available module which could be used as a plugin to the apache server to provide the functionality of the brokers.

I have done my research for this and have found no solution so far. All I have come across are few vendors which offer cloud based services for MQ and not any stand alone product which could be installed on the cloud.

I know cloud are not the best options for creating enterprise level infrastructure which clustered servers in LAN/WAN can provide. I am just looking for available options if any.

Thank in advance for your answers.

Comment: I've not used these systems, so cannot myself offer advice, but can you expand on why you say "I know cloud [servers] are not the best options for creating enterprise level infrastructure"? (Also note that, whilst interesting, this question sounds like a request for software recommendations, and as such is probably off-topic on Stack Overflow. You may get some thoughts in the comments).

Comment: regarding the comment about the cloud.... Its just my opinion... I know about some on demand solutions which do operate on from the cloud. But they do pose dependency on Internet connectivity... I have seen some issues in my experience where the Lan/Wan is completely working but the solution on cloud are not accessible because the Internet is not available. This might be just one observation that might not fit all the scenarios and can not be generalized.

Comment: It sounds like your object to running a message queue on a cloud host is too vague to be a real objection. Choose the queue system you like, get it working in your local development environment, and worry about deploying it later. Since cloud is basically just a scalable VPS, I don't think you'll have any problems from this perspective (you'll need to ensure your architecture works, but that's a separate issue really).

Comment: Just FYI but IBM MQ does *not* have to run on a stand-alone server as stated in the question. The original design was that the MQ queue manager was housed locally with the application. Remember that MQ was invented in large part to solve problems of unreliable networks. The local queuing capability is in fact its native implementation.

Answer (score 2):

[MQ Light](https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/mq-light/) is available both as a standalone download or can be used as a service via the Bluemix IBM cloud offering.  When you have created an MQ Light application locally, you can choose to deploy it to the cloud using MQ Light Service for Bluemix.

[IBM MQ Hypervisor Edition](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.hypervisor.doc/hy00100_.htm?cp=SSFKSJ_7.5.0%2F7) is specially tailored for use with IBM Workload Deployer and IBM Pure Application Systems, which are both flavors of cloud platforms.

IBM has also provided an [Amazon Machine Image](https://aws.amazon.com/items/3645?externalID=3645) with MQ included and a bring-your-own-license model.

Comment: Please note that MQ Light as a Bluemix service has now been deprecated and replaced in Bluemix with the Message Hub service which still can use the MQ Light API.

Answer (score 0):

IBM has [announced MQ Cloud](https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/2017/11/08/statement-direction-ibm-mq-cloud-offering/) product to be available in the near future. The MQ cloud offering is intended to be compatible with on-premise MQ offerings. Within the constraints of a cloud environment, users would be able to use the same development tooling for both the cloud and on-premise software.

Comment: Valerie, there is only one question tagged [ibmmqcloud], I think I would prefer to see it tagged [ibm-mq].  This puts it with 3.1k other IBM MQ related questions and 625 watchers of that tag.  That compares to the [ibmmqcloud] tag with 1 question and 6 watchers.  We also don't split out for instance MQ Appliance on this site.  Please let me know if you have any reservations about retagging this to [ibm-mq], also note that once the [ibmmqcloud] tag has no questions it will automatically go away.

Comment: Josh, changed tag per your comment

Comment: Thank you Valerie.  I think the tag cleanup happens overnight.